# Autoreturn after external command

Tags: external-command

When I run the following command ex:

`:! some_command`

It's somewhat annoying the message:

> Press ENTER or type command to continue

Is there a way to automatically return to current buffer without press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>?

Comment: `:help press-enter`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A way to do this is to use the `silent` command:

```
:silent !ls
```

This will return to normal mode right after the command (here `ls` has been executed).

In the case the command produces output, you may want to force a redraw of the screen with the `redraw` command:

```
:execute "silent !ls" | redraw!
```

You can even create a new command that does this for you:

```
command! -nargs=+ Silent execute 'silent <args>' | redraw!
```

And use it like so:

```
:Silent !ls
```

Comment: Amazing! @nobe4